# Laravel 5 - How to send url paramaters in form

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a form with some input in a search page who has an URL with many parameters and I want to send them in this form or any other way . 
Form code

```
  {!! Form::open(['route' => ['test.mail'],'method' => 'post','files' => true]) !!}
            {!! Form::token() !!}
                    <div class="box-header">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                        <h3 class="box-title">Quick Email</h3>
                        <!-- tools box -->
                        <div class="pull-right box-tools">
                            <!--<button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-widget="remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>-->
                        </div><!-- /. tools -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-body">


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="object" placeholder="Subject" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="textarea" name="textu" placeholder="Message"  cols="120" rows="8"></textarea>
                        </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="filee"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-footer clearfix">
                        <input type="submit"  name="sendEmail" class="pull-right btn btn-default" id="sendEmail" value="Send">
                    </div>
                  {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you get all the values in your url

```
foreach($_GET as $key=>$value){
    echo $key, ' => ', $value, "<br/>n";
}
```

then to send them in your form you simply create an input type hidden like this:

```
<input id="someId" name="UrlValue" type="hidden" value="$UrlValue">
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help,

```
// Get the current URL without the query string...
echo url()->current();

// Get the current URL including the query string...
echo url()->full();

// Get the full URL for the previous request...
echo url()->previous();
```

Each of these methods may also be accessed via the URL facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

echo URL::current();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/urls